# Hartshorne corollary 5.20 in chapter two.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In his book, the corollary states as

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y $ be a projective morphism of schemes of finite type over a field $k$. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$. Then $f_*\mathscr{F}$ is coherent on $Y$.

My first question is that in the statement what exactly is defined over field $k$. From the definitions, I can't see where $k$ plays a role.

Second, in his proof, he uses $\widetilde{\Gamma(Y,f_* \mathscr{F}})=\widetilde{\Gamma(X, \mathscr{F}})$. How could we deduce this? Is this always true for arbitrary morphisms and schemes?

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean Hartshorne?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig. Yes, thank you for pointing it out. I edited the title.

Comment: One small issue: you have used $f^*$ when you ought to have used $f_*$ - then the global sections agree by definition of the direct image sheaf. For your larger question, check theorem III.5.2 for another proof of theorem II.5.19 without the hypothesis of being over a field.